# how to accessing my web application on netbeans and glassfish server from my phone

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm working on ejb project using netbeans,glassfish server and java db.

The project work nice on my localhost and I can put my ip address instead of my localhost and it work prefect also.

`192.168.1.156:8080/project/` work well from my PC.

`LOCALHOST:8080/PROJECT/` work well from my PC.

Now I'm trying to access this project from my phone using my local ip address and 8080 port but it doesn't work.

How can I access my project from remote machine on the same LAN?

I work on windows 7 OS.

Thank you.

Comment: you must create firewall rule to allow access on 8080 port in your lan.

Comment: i create rule and turn off firewall but nothing happens i try to ping to other divices but it not reachable